# Add/enable VScroll in Richtextbox with content dynamically loaded at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to build a simple UI which is divided into left and right panels. On the left is a tree view built inside a richtextbox (RTB) with clickable links. On the right it is a WebBrowser. The content of the RTB is loaded dynamically at runtime. It may exceed the height of the RTB so there is a need for vertical scrolling.

I have set some key properties of the RTB (as shown below) but failed to see the VScroll enabled even though the content in it is more than it can display.

So here are some code snippets:
            private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            .........

```
        this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
        this.SidePane = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.Browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 25);
        this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.SidePane);
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.AutoScroll = true;
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.Browser);
        this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1110, 501);
        this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 127;
        this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // SidePane
        // 
        this.SidePane.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        this.SidePane.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
        this.SidePane.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
        this.SidePane.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
        this.SidePane.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.SidePane.Name = "SidePane";
        this.SidePane.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth;
        this.SidePane.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 481);
        this.SidePane.TabIndex = 0;
        this.SidePane.Text = "";
        this.SidePane.WordWrap = false;

        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1110, 548);
        this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.address);
        this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.statusbar);
        this.Controls.Add(this.GoButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ForwardButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.BackButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.statusbar.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.statusbar.PerformLayout();
        this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer1)).EndInit();
        this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private void loadInit(string file)
    {
        // load data from a file
        ............

        foreach (String node in nodes)
        {

            Hashtable hash = (Hashtable) parser.GetInitPairs(node);

            // create nodes of a tree view as lables and add them to the RTB
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "[" + node + "]";
            lbl.Font = new Font("Arial", size);
            int x = X1, y = Y1;
            Point p = new Point(x, y);
            lbl.Location = p;
            this.SidePane.Controls.Add(lbl);
            Y1 += incr;

            // grab the links as sub-nodes and add them to the RTB
            foreach(String key in hash.Keys)
            {
                String val = (String) hash[key];
                Label klbl = new Label();
                klbl.Text = key;
                int X = X2, Y = Y1;
                Point kp = new Point(X, Y);
                klbl.Location = kp;
                klbl.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                klbl.Font = new Font("Arial", size);

                // Clickable event handlers
                klbl.DoubleClick += (s, e) => { Browser.Navigate(/*node == "Poll"*/ val.Contains("{0}") && symbol != null ? String.Format(val, symbol) : val); klbl.ForeColor = Color.CadetBlue; };

                this.SidePane.Controls.Add(klbl);               

                Y1 += incr;
            }

        }

    }
```

I appreciate if you can help to address these problems: 1) enable the VScroll when there is more content than display; 2) take care of event handling if user scroll up or down of the RTB area.

Comment: You can't reasonalbly use the RichTextBox as a container control.  If you want a TreeView, use a TreeView,

Comment: I have no problem using RTB as container for labels. It works, although it may not be the best solution. My problem is that I can't set the vertical scroll right.

Comment: But a RichTextBox is for text, which is why the scrollbar isn't behaving the way you want.  Replace the RichTextBox with just a simple panel with AutoScroll = true.

Comment: You are right, I removed the RTB and put everything into the left panel. It works. Thank you!